# overlapping two plots in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I've two plots generated using matplotlib. The first represents my backround and the second a group of points which I want to show. Is there a way to overlap the two plots?

background:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10))
grid_duomo = gpd.read_file('/content/Griglia_2m-SS.shp')  
grid_duomo.to_crs(epsg=32632).plot(ax=ax, color='lightgrey')
```

points:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ids = traj_collection_df_new_app['id'].unique()
for id_ in ids:
  self_id = traj_collection_df_new_app[traj_collection_df_new_app['id'] == id_]
  plt.plot(
            self_id['lon'],
            self_id['lat'],
            # markers= 'o',
            # markersize=12
        )
```

[image: background]

[image: points]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you'd just remove the call to `plt.figure`, and run the two parts in one go, matplotlib normally would compose them nicely.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.plot()` will always take the most recent axis found by matplotlib and use it for plotting.

Its practically the same as `plt.gca().plot()` where `plt.gca()` stands for "get current axis".

To get full control over which axis is used, you should do something like this:
(the `zorder` argument is used to set the "vertical stacking" of the artists, e.g. `zorder=2` will be plotted on top of `zorder=1`)

```py
f = plt.figure()            # create a figure
ax = f.add_subplot( ... )   # create an axis in the figure f

ax.plot(..., zorder=0)
grid_duomo.plot(ax=ax, ..., zorder=1)

# you can then continue to add more axes to the same figure using 
# f.add_subplot() or f.add_axes()
```

(if this is unclear, maybe check the [quick_start](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/quick_start.html) guide of matplotlib? )